# Count 2 columns from join query in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query which returns values from one column and splits into two columns based on the value.
What I'm trying to achieve now is getting a count of each value for each column. I've tried a variety of count options, but all continue to fail with different errors.

Here's a sample result of the query

```
GROUP_ID   SUBS DEPS
123456ABCD  20  70
123456ABCD  10  70
123456ABCD  20  70
123456ABCD  10  70
123456ABCD  20  70
123456ABCD  10  70
123456ABCD  10  70
123456ABCD  10  70
123456ABCD  20  70
123456ABCD  10  70
```

Ultimately, I'd like one row with the GROUP_ID, totals SUBS count and total DEPS count

This is the query that I'm using:

```
SELECT a.MEMBGRP as GROUP_ID ,
a.MEMBCD as SUBS, b.MEMBCD as DEPS
FROM MEMBTABLE  a
INNER JOIN MEMBTABLE  b on
(a.MEMBGRP = b.MEMBGRP and a.MEMBCD < 21 and b.MEMBCD > 20)
where a.MEMBGRP = '123456ABCD'
```

Comment: When you say "count of each value", what exactly do you mean? For your sample query output, what is your expected result?

Comment: What results do you want?

Comment: "MEMBCD" is a single column. I need the count from that column but it needs to be separated into two columns 1) anything less than 21 (SUBS) and 2) anything over 20 (DEPS). I also need the MEMBGRP reported back as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your needs can be simplified:

```
SELECT 
  a.MEMBGRP as GROUP_ID ,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN a.MEMBCD <= 20 THEN a.MEMBCD END) as SUBS, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN a.MEMBCD > 20 THEN a.MEMBCD END) as DEPS
FROM MEMBTABLE  a
WHERE a.MEMBGRP = '123456ABCD'
GROUP BY a.MEMBGRP
```

It works because when the value is eg less than 21 the case when will return the value otherwise it will return null, and count doesn't count nulls

Removing the join will improve performance. This query essentially answers the question "how many different values of MEMBCD are 20 or below, and how many different values of MEMBCD are above 20, for a given MEMBGRP"

It will return a result like:

```
123456ABCD  2 1
```

Because there are 2 unique values in the SUBS (20 and 10) and one unique value in the DEPS (70)

---

If you aren't counting different/unique values but instead are counting all values, ie "how many rows have a value of MEMBCD that is 20 or below, and how many rows have a value of MEMBCD that is above 20, for a given MEMBGRP", remove the word DISTINCT from inside each count

I can't easily give an example result set for this because the result set you posted could be a Cartesian product but for source data of:

```
123456ABCD 20
123456ABCD 20
123456ABCD 10
123456ABCD 5
123456ABCD 50
123456ABCD 70
```

It would produce a result of

```
123456ABCD  4  2
```

Because four of the values (20, 20, 10, 5) are below 21 and two of the values (50, 70) are above 20

If you want to know results for all occurrences of MEMBGRP remove the where clause

Comment: This is it! I removed DISTINCT and am now getting all of the occurrences as I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I beleive you want to count the unique values in 2 columns so you can use `group by` with `distinct` as following:

```
SELECT a.MEMBGRP as GROUP_ID ,
Count(distinct a.MEMBCD) as SUBS, count(distinct b.MEMBCD) as DEPS
FROM MEMBTABLE  a
INNER JOIN MEMBTABLE  b on
(a.MEMBGRP = b.MEMBGRP and a.MEMBCD < 21 and b.MEMBCD > 20)
where a.MEMBGRP = '123456ABCD'
Group by a.MEMBGRP;
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your request it looks like you need a group by and a count.

```
SELECT a.MEMBGRP as GROUP_ID 
       ,count(a.MEMBCD) as SUBS
       ,count(b.MEMBCD) as DEPS
  FROM MEMBTABLE  a
GROUP BY a.MEMBGRP
```

Could you explain the logic to be used that you have done

(a.MEMBGRP = b.MEMBGRP and a.MEMBCD < 21 and b.MEMBCD > 20)

what is the goal here

Comment: The goal here is to separate the MEMBCD column into two separate columns (SUBS and DEPS) based on the MEMBCD value. If the value is less than 21, put in the SUBS column, if the value is over 20, put in the DEPS column.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Count` in you query.

```
SELECT a.MEMBGRP as GROUP_ID ,t2.MEMBCD SUBS,count(a.MEMBCD) DEPS
FROM MEMBTABLE  a
INNER JOIN (Select Count(MEMBCD) as MEMBCD,MEMBGRP From MEMBTABLE b where b.MEMBCD > 20 group by b.MEMBGRP) t2 
where a.MEMBGRP = '123456ABCD' and a.MEMBCD < 21 group by t2.MEMBGRP
```

[**dbfiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e3d60ca9f6175201d428ece78b92892d)